# How can i find an estimation of the inverse operator $\|(I - T)^{-1}\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, spectral-theory

$T$ is a bounded linear operator such that $\|T\| \leq e^{a}$; where $a > 0$.\
if the operator $I - T$ is invertible,\
How can i find an estimation of $\|(I - T)^{-1}\|$.

thanks;

Comment: From $\|T\| \le e^a$ with $a>0$ you cannot conclude that $I-T$ is invertible at all.

Comment: my operator I - T is invertible

Comment: There are some estimates in case $a<0$, but I guess these do not interest you, right?

Comment: Thanks.  But my operator norm is not less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

The information you have does not give any information on the size of $||(T-I)^{-1}||$:

> > For every $A<\infty$ there exists $T$ with $||T||<1$, $T-I$ invertible and $||(T-I)^{-1}||>A$.

Proof: Say $0<\epsilon<1/A$. Define $T:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ by $$Tz=(1-\epsilon)z.$$

Comment: Always nice if the proof is shorter than the statement (+1). I guess you miss a $<$ after the $A$.